# Faster page links loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was browsing this website https://amaioswim.com/
and I did notice that when clicking on the navigation on the left side, the url address change instantly.

They also use a "fade out" and "Fade in" curtain to make the transition between pages seamless.

I'm wondering what kind of approach would you use to achieve this.

I know with JS you can change url, but only hashtags url... right?
or is it because they have a super fast server with 0 latency?

do you think they are loading everything ajax-ly in a same dvi container?

Thanks

Comment: On top of what's been answered, the way they have the seamless transition is (most likely) using a front end framework like angular or react.

Answer (score 2):

This has little to do with the history API.  (They are using that API to update the displayed URL, but that's a minor detail in how the site works; on its own it wouldn't create this behavior.)

This particular site is running a clientside framework. (I'm not seeing any obvious clues in the minified code as to which one.)

Links within the site are handled as AJAX requests. They're using the same endpoints for fresh page loads and for XHR calls, and are checking the `X-Requested-With` header  to determine whether to send the full server-rendered HTML file (including the framework for the full site) or just the content for that particular page (which will be embedded clientside in the already loaded site.)

As evidence: this returns the full site (as when a user first visits that URL):

```
curl 'https://amaioswim.com/about'
```

This returns just the "about" content (as when a user clicks the "about" link after loading the site):

```
curl 'https://amaioswim.com/about' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
```

(You can also see this by viewing the Network panel in the browser console while navigating the site.)

Loading just the content for an individual page is, of course, much faster than loading the entire page HTML (and its CSS and JS), and allows you to add glossy effects like crossfades and animations while the AJAX call is in progress.

Comment: Can you furbish a baseline example of this in action?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: The code to achieve what you outlined in detail above.  We have the website as the example of the result, we have your explanation of what is going on, but no simple code example, unless ofcourse, the code would not be simple but cumbersome.

Comment: Yeah, "how do clientside/SPA frameworks work" is a huge subject, I'm afraid it isn't really the sort of thing that can be broken down into a simple code example.  There are plenty of getting-started tutorials for Angular, React, Vue, Meteor, etc., if someone wanted to replicate this sort of thing that's where I'd suggest starting.

Comment: Well it is definately *using* the history API, but of course there are lots of other things going on. When viewing the code I repeatedly find a the word "shopify", so I would guess that the site is built on their platform (see https://www.shopify.com/). A platform like this takes a lot of effort to write. I can see a reference to jquery, the rest of the stuff might just be a proprietary shopify framework. According to wikipedia "The company reports that it has more than 500,000 merchants using its platform" so they have the resources to build advanced stuff. Its not just used by this site

Answer (score 1):

Since some years you can use the html5 history api:

https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/

It will allow you to manipulate the url quite freely.
For example when you scroll to a new section you can put that section at the end of the browser url.

Answer (score 1):

That's history API in action. Find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Try the `pushState` and `replaceState` methods, that should get you this behavior. To have more precise control over these, you might also want to take a look at `popState` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate)